# Typescript jsx tag is not equal with React.createElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

```
// myComponentJSX is JSX.Element
const myComponentJSX = <MyComponent prop1="foo" prop2={1} />;

// myComponentJSX is React.FunctionComponentElement<Props>
const myComponentJSX = React.createElement(MyComponent, { prop1: 'foo', prop2: 1 });
```

How can I keep the Type when use `<MyComponent prop1="foo" prop2={1} />`?

[https://www.typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUI8AHYxZQF5ZwAKxYdAG9GcOGAEBGAFxxUMKKwDmAGnECATLJYBXEACMOjAL6NcEFvLgBZAJ4BhEpBZY2cALxwAFEPUQwkmoS-hpwxrL8-qgAlB4AfHAiDGKUMDpQLHAAPAAmwABucULBAcYAtMWaxlkA9HmFJoyMNTVwAFIAygAajFgAHpCwcOaW8J1dACJYIBCy2HgwAHQAYvZZyCy2CZ5e0bLjiwCiADbTrvDuCUliLXAgDk4W5+P73UenIOeiwxZW947gJ5scYebJ2AHOc5+ALuABEBAgEFh0I07iEkmMcBqcXoySxrX+jxcwO6cyoS2WOhY+GAFghQJgJzObHWmzi3xGfwegOJMGwaQyoPm+EWuGOTyZnzYXkJPOe3WiuJSWAFmVlkLY-PSLEaTAYt1wlGQ7ElXwY-UG8E5VqNJo+5ymMzJCxWaw2W1Bu1eXXezIuV2+t3VDJemHJKypNLpRPOppZkUE7Lx1ru3I1MBBnmFS0NODtfq84JjbDUvhKMnICIgZCCmlkkjCisDBLTDK1GWdIsp1JgtJY9N5cZgWQTqCTYhTwd57cyWfDYol9ulU-lXSbeNS2tTA-OM5MQA)

Comment: Why do you need to keep the type in the first place? You can use React's types instead of JSX types; e.g. look at `React.ReactChild`..?

Comment: @AKX I need `React.cloneElement(myComponentJSX, { prop1: 'bar' })` with type, so I know `prop1` is valid. and VSCode has `code suggestion` for `prop1`.